# How do I use a variable pattern with preg_match?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I don't know if this is enough data to feed off of, but I have

> preg_match('/SAMPLETEXT/', $bcurl, $cookie1);

and I was wondering if I can make it

> preg_match($newfunction, $bcurl, $cookie1);

but when I do, I get this error "Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash in".

How can I make it check for my new function, rather than have it check just for "SAMPLETEXT".

Comment: What is the value of $newfunction?

Comment: The value of $newfunction consists of a random key string of around 5-10 numbers that is inserted into the SQL on another file, on load.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try `preg_match("/$newfunction/", $bcurl, $cookie1);` so that you are providing the required  delimiters (using a delimiter that isn't going to be in $newfunction).

But note that the [documentation](http://php.net/preg_match) says "Do not use preg_match() if you only want to check if one string is contained in another string. Use strpos() or strstr() instead as they will be faster."

Comment: This was a pure failure. It was checking the website for $function instead of the the actual random key that $function is.

Comment: @Joey: Did you use double quotes or single quotes?

Comment: @Joey: where $bcurl comes from is really irrelevant.  Either the preg_match is going to work or it isn't.  Did you use double quotes as in my example?

Comment: You are amazing, thanks! It works! I didn't use double quotes before. I scanned passed your answer, and didn't look at it clearly, thanks so much. :)

Comment: Remember that you should escape the contents of `$newfunction` with preg_quote if it can contain reserved characters for regular expressions, such as `.`, `\` or `?`.

Answer (score 8):

`preg_match('/'.$pattern.'/i', $subject)`

`i` option: allow capital letters or hyphen.

Answer (score -4):

u can use variable by putting it between []

```
    $subject = "abcdef";
$ch = 'b';
$pattern = '/[$ch]/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
//print_r($matches);
if ($matches)
{
    echo $subject;
}
```

Comment: This only looks like it works because the variable _name_ contains a c.